# How to trigger a webpage in a post request in NodeJS?

Tags: html, node.js, post, get

Bellow is the code I want to request a post method like `/zamansecimi` and I want to open a page like `rapor.ejs` according to data from `/zamansecimi`.

How can I do this?

```
<form  method="post" action="/zamansecimi"  >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ad">Başlangıç</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="baslangic" id="baslangic"  placeholder="" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="soyad">Bitiş</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="bitis" id="bitis" placeholder="" required>
    </div>            
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" value="rapor" class="btn btn-primary">Göster</button>
    </div>

      </div> 
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your backend will need to respond with a `redirect` when the endpoint (`/zamansecimi`) is called.

If you are using `express` you can the doc here https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect